# Hibernate CrudRepository native query not returning result with to_timestamp function

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using oracle as db. I need to write a native query and store the result as list. The native query i am trying to run works perfectly using sqldeveloper tool. But when i try it with CrudRepository result returns an empty list.
I am basically trying to retrieve the data from the current month that we are in.

created_at is a timestamp field in database

Below is my code

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<City, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT plate,SUM(TOTAL_PRICE) as total FROM sale_item_ok where company_id =2 and created_at >= TO_TIMESTAMP (TRUNC(sysdate,'mm'),'DD/MM/YYYY') and created_at < TO_TIMESTAMP (TRUNC(add_months(sysdate,1),'mm'),'DD/MM/YYYY') group by plate order by total desc) WHERE ROWNUM<=5"
                   , nativeQuery = true)
    List<item> findCustomVehicles();

}
```

Projection Interface

```
public interface item{

    String getPlate();
    int getTotal();
}
```

As a starting point i think there is a problem usin the to_timestamp method with hibernate. When i update the where condition like below and remove to_timestamp part, it works fine and return the results.

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<City, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT plate,SUM(TOTAL_PRICE) as total FROM sale_item_ok where company_id =2 group by plate order by total desc) WHERE ROWNUM<=5"
                   , nativeQuery = true)
    List<item> findCustomVehicles();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this once ? 
Using the method **createNativeQuery(sqlString, resultClass)**
Native queries can also be defined dynamically using the EntityManager.createNativeQuery()

```
String sql = "YOUR_QUERY WHERE ID = ?";
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql, item.class);
query.setParameter(1, id);
item itemObj= (item) query.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: hello, i tried createNativeQuery but still no luck with to_timestamp unfortunately

Comment: @blackened8333 , can you please provide screenshot of your data from database ? So that I get idea what is your data type in table and how you are converting.